# Truecrypt remote password

Tags: security, truecrypt

TrueCrypt as  a pre-boot authentication  is it possible that the password  is sent remotely by the usb that receive the password from GSM or EDGE/3G/4G connected  to the   device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truecrypt (and other Software I know of) only supports Passwords in the PreBoot mode for system encryption. USB Devices like your keyboard is supported by the BIOS of your PC, there are no drivers for accessing any modem or network (or smartcard for that matter).

If you really want this: create, program or buy an usb device that simulates a keyboard and manages its own network connection with an onboard modem.